# PySide2 updating a graph

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, qt5, pyside2

I have been knocking my head against the wall on the following issue for quite some times now and need some fresh pair of eyes to help me out.

In Qt Designer I created a tab with a QComboBox (to select a feature), a QPushButton (to instruct the plotting of the feature) and a QWidget (plot area, called mywidget). The whole code is largely inspired from various codes found on SO.

In main.py I connected the QPushButton to the following function (defined within my QtApp class):

```
def launchGraph(self):
    df1 = ... #data from a data source
    self.mywidget.figure = Figure()
    self.mywidget.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.mywidget.figure)
    self.mywidget.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.mywidget.canvas, self)

    self.mywidget.graphLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    self.mywidget.graphLayout.addWidget(self.mywidget.canvas)
    self.mywidget.graphLayout.addWidget(self.mywidget.toolbar)
    self.mywidget.setLayout(self.mywidget.graphLayout)

    ax1f1 = self.mywidget.figure.add_subplot(111)
    ax1f1.clear()
    ax1f1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b%-y'))
    ax1f1.plot(df1['x'], df1['y'], linewidth=1, color='blue')
    ax1f1.set(title='My Little Graph')
    self.mywidget.canvas.draw()
```

The issue is that when I launched my window, select a feature and click the button, the correct graph is being shown. If I changed the feature and click the plot button, nothing happens. I did print the feature of the combobox and it prints the correct up-to-date value from the combobox however the graph is not replaced/updated. I also added a test-variable isgraph and used self.mywidget.figure.clear() but no success neither. canvas.repaint() doesn't update the graph neither. It feels like I need to use a test-variable to check whether a graph is there or not and if yes then I need to clen up the content of mywidget. But that seems overcomplicated for this issue (?)

For info I import the following:

```
from gui import main
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas, 
                                                NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)
```

**Edit:**
Here is the minimal/adapted full code:

```
from gui import main
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (FigureCanvasQTAgg as 
FigureCanvas, NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)

class MyQtApp(main.Ui_MainWindow, QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyQtApp, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.graphBtn.clicked.connect(self.launchGraph)

        self.show()

    def launchGraph(self):
        if self.mycb.currrentText() == 'feature1':
            df1 = ... #data from a data source
        else: (#== feature2)
            df1 = ... #some other data

        self.mywidget.figure = Figure()
        self.mywidget.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.mywidget.figure)
        self.mywidget.toolbar = 
                         NavigationToolbar(self.mywidget.canvas, self)

        self.mywidget.graphLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.mywidget.graphLayout.addWidget(self.mywidget.canvas)
        self.mywidget.graphLayout.addWidget(self.mywidget.toolbar)
        self.mywidget.setLayout(self.mywidget.graphLayout)

        ax = self.mywidget.figure.add_subplot(111)
        ax.clear()
        ax.plot(df1['x'], df1['y'])
        self.mywidget.canvas.draw()
```

In Qt Designer (file main.ui comnverted into. main.py), I placed:
- one combobox, called mycb and having 2 values: [feature1, feature2]
- one push button, called graphBtn
- a simple and empty QWidget called mywidget

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely, that when you run the `launchGraph` after the initial run, the function creates another `ax1f1` underneath the initial one. Therefore the initial one keeps on showing and no errors are displayed.

In this particular case, you want to keep working with the initial `ax1f1` instead of re-declaring another one.

Something like this could fix the problem:

```
def launchGraph(self):
    if self.mycb.currrentText() == 'feature1':
        df1 = ['some_data'] #data from a data source
    else: (#== feature2)
        df1 = ['some_other_data'] #some other data
    self.mywidget.figure = Figure()
    self.mywidget.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.mywidget.figure)
    self.mywidget.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.mywidget.canvas, self)

    self.mywidget.graphLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    self.mywidget.graphLayout.addWidget(self.mywidget.canvas)
    self.mywidget.graphLayout.addWidget(self.mywidget.toolbar)
    self.mywidget.setLayout(self.mywidget.graphLayout)

    try:
        self.ax1f1.clear()
    except:
        self.a1f1 = self.mywidget.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.ax1f1.clear()

    self.ax1f1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b%-y'))
    self.ax1f1.plot(df1['x'], df1['y'], linewidth=1, color='blue')
    self.ax1f1.set(title='My Little Graph')
    self.mywidget.canvas.draw()
```